# FormatConditions Add rule if not number

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a range I want to create format conditions for.  It is mostly numbers, however, there can be "N/A" in the range from time to time.  Every time an "N/A" shows up, it is using the 3rd FormatConditions.  How can I get these rules to catch if it is not numeric or contains the only possible string "N/A"?  Thanks in advance.

```
Set sRange = Range("B2:B" & slastRow - 2)
sRange.FormatConditions.Delete

sRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=.80"    'Below 80%
sRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 41, 41) 'Red
sRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=.80", Formula2:="=.8999" 'Between 80 & 90%
sRange.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 41) 'Yellow
sRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=.8999"  '90% and above
sRange.FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = RGB(41, 255, 41) 'Green
sRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="N/A", TextOperator:=xlContains
sRange.FormatConditions(4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check against the text first to achieve what you're looking for. I've modified the code you gave by putting the text validation first, since the number values were triggering true before the text validation.

```
Set sRange = Range("B2:B" & slastRow - 2)
sRange.FormatConditions.Delete

srange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ISTEXT(B2)"
srange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White
srange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=.80"    'Below 80%
srange.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 41, 41) 'Red
srange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=.80", Formula2:="=.8999" 'Between 80 & 90%
srange.FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 41) 'Yellow
srange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=.8999"  '90% and above
srange.FormatConditions(4).Interior.Color = RGB(41, 255, 41) 'Green
```

Comment: Cleaner code...just needed to change to B2 and it worked great!

Answer (score 1):

- The 1st FC is for non-numeric values in col B.

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim sRange As Range, sLastRow  As Long
    Dim oFC As FormatCondition
    sLastRow = 10 ' for testing
    Set sRange = Range("B2:B" & sLastRow - 2)
    With sRange.FormatConditions
        .Delete
        Set oFC = sRange.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NOT(ISNUMBER(B2))")
        '    Set oFC = sRange.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlTextString, String:="N/A", TextOperator:=xlEqual)
        oFC.StopIfTrue = True
        oFC.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White
        Set oFC = .Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=.80")      'Below 80%
        oFC.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 41, 41) 'Red
        Set oFC = .Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=.80", Formula2:="=.8999")  'Between 80 & 90%
        oFC.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 41) 'Yellow
        Set oFC = .Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=.8999")   '90% and above
        oFC.Interior.Color = RGB(41, 255, 41) 'Green
    End With
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [FormatConditions.Add method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions.add?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: It's recommend to use `Set oFC = .Add(..)  oFC.Interior.Color =  ...` instead of  `srange.FormatConditions(x)`. It is difficult to track what's the index of new added FC if there are many FCs in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Any text in Excel is "greater" than any number. So if you want to exclude only this single text "N/A" (a text not error code) move this rule as a first one, before numbers.
If you want to exclude all non-numbers, you can use a rule `Operator:=xlGreater` with a very big number (which you don't use) e.g. `1E6` and place it as a first condition.